# Smart Search in <select> for grails and angularjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, grails

I want to add smart search to the  dropdown in grails angularjs application. Does any one know how I can do that ? I get the data for the list from a table through MySQL.
I use ng-model and ng-option. I use the following code.

```
<select class="something" id="filter.customer.id" name="filter.customer.id"
       ng-model="ctrl.customer"
       ng-option="ctrl.customer"
     <option value=""><{something}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I've done a "searchable" select with angularjs and grails using ui-select (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select). You might wanna give it a try.

Comment: I have tried ui-select but it doesnt have search in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter to a [**`ng-options`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Here I created an input to **search a customer ID**. The data in the `select` will be filtered from this value.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search"></input>
<select ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="c as c.id for c in customers | filter: {id: search}"></select>
```

**[Check this demo application example](http://jsfiddle.net/kvskmwg0/)**